# Adding own experience as follow up on the question?

Tags: discussion

A while back I asked a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119739/is-it-common-accepted-to-bring-a-dog-in-tuscany-italy) about my holiday to Italy. I was wondering what the common etiquette towards dogs in restaurants in Tuscany was.

I got a lovely answer and we went ahead and followed the advice. It worked out well, our experience was even better than the answer portrayed.

Is it appreciated/expected to write a 'follow up' in this case? Should I edit the question, post a comment or maybe add an answer of my own?

Comment: You can add an answer as your own, totally fine.  A nice comment is also useful, or an acceptance of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If your experience is along the same lines as the answer given, please accept it with (maybe) a comment added that it worked out that way.

If your experience was enough different that you would like to write about it more than one or two lines to give people a different view, please write that as an answer.
On the other hand, if one or two lines are enough, you can add that to the question.

You can still accept the original answer if not already done so, or you can accept your own answer, I would only to that last if your experience was in conflict with earlier answer(s) but you are always free to un-accept answers and accept an other, including your own.

And remember that comments do tend to get lost over time if there is more activity on the question where answers and edits to the question tend to stay.